# How can I show the stock information in odoo e-shop

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo-website, odoo-product-configurator

how can I show the stock info on my website in odoo.
I made some research and tried the add this to `website_sale/views/templates.xml`

[image]

```
<h1 t-field="product.qty_available"/>
```

but it's giving me an error when rendering the template

```
KeyError: 'qty_available'
Template: 1439
Path: /t/t[4]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/h1[2]
Node: <h1 t-field="product.qty_available" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/t[4]/div[1]/section[1]/div[2]/div[2]/h1[2]"/>
```

How can i manage this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product `qty_available` field is declared in [stock](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/stock/models/product.py#L31) module.

You need to install the `stock` module to be able to use it